# Border radius of container inside card

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When I try to set the border radius of the top two corners of my container that is nested inside a card, the whole content of the container goes disappears. Here is my code, if you uncomment the commented line your whole content inside the container will go away.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      ),
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: new Border(
              top: BorderSide(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            width: 3.0,
          )),
          //borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: const Radius.circular(5.0)),
        ),
        child: makeListTile(widget.flight),
      ),
    );
```

}

Answer (score 31):

Just add

```
clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias
```

To Card

Comment: This is a very good solution that haunted me for a very long time! Thanks Bro

Answer (score 9):

```
      Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: new Border(
                top: BorderSide(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              width: 3.0,
            )),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0)),
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ),
      )
```

I tried your code it works fine its only that the corner is getting hidden due to the card's corner look you have specified same radius for container and card,I just added a width and height to container and increased the circular radius to make the change visible,

[image]

I dont know why you are using the container inside a card if you want a card with only lefttop corner circular then you can do this by the below code,I recommend you to look at [the ways of creating cards in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56891649/8253662)

```
SizedBox.expand(
          child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
              side: BorderSide(width: 2.5, color: Colors.black)),
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        ),
        )
```

[image]

if you have any questions feel free to comment

Comment: The problem with just doing it in the card is that I can't just set the borderTop color.

Comment: if you could leave some link to an image may be I can help

Comment: If you look at your second box of code, you do 'margin: EdgeInsets.all(10)' . This sets the box border instead of just doing top border