# Flutter card elevation not applying on card top

Tags: flutter, dart, elevation, card

When adding a container inside a card widget then elevation of card is not applying on top of card.

```
Card(
  elevation: 10,
  shadowColor: Colors.green,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // widget goes here
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      // some more widgets
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347831/how-can-i-make-a-shadow-with-a-material-design-card

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working ?? It is working fine. Demo https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=8bcda2bd98dff23b270eecaf8eb376fc

Comment: @OMiShah look at the top of the card. elevation is not applying to top of card.

Comment: @Phanindra, you probably want to look into ``shadow`` instead of ``elevation`` then. Don't get confused between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Container decoration instead of Card elevation

```
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.5),
        spreadRadius: 5,
        blurRadius: 7,
        offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
      ),
    ],
  ),
child:Column(), //your widget here
)
```

Comment: I want have a ripple effect on click, so I have to using Card, container does have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Align(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text("SOMETHING")
                      // widget goes here
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            color: Colors.orange,
            elevation: 10,
            shadowColor: Colors.green,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
```

[image]